# TCPDF: get remaining width relative to the bottom margin of every page

Tags: php, tcpdf

I've been stuck with this problem for a while now. The thing is I need to output "--- end of page ---" for remaining whitespace of every page.

Screenshot:
[image]
The page content is generated dynamically.

I came up with this logic:

1. getRemainingWidth() of each page
2. then find the horizontal and vertical center from start point (bottom margin minus RemainingWidth) to bottom
   margin
3. and output "end of page"

Anyone solved this before?

thanks!

Answer (score 9):

All of the bits and pieces you'll need are available in the API: www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html

You'll need `GetY()` to get the current position of the "cursor" after that last paragraph has been written. Let's call this y1.

Width-wise it looks like you want the box to be the same as the paragraph margins, which you presumably already know if you're writing that text yourself. x1 will be whatever the left margin is and x2 will be the page width from `GetPageWidth()` minus the current right margin.

Presumably you also know how far down the page you want the box to extend, which we'll call y2. You will then need to calculate the width and height prior to calling `Rect()` to draw the box. Don't forget to set the drawing color first with `SetDrawColor()`.

Then you can use `Line()` to draw the two diagonal lines.

Finally, you'll need to prepare a few things before you can write the '..end of page...' text, such as:

- Setting the font style, color, etc
- Calling `SetY()` with y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2 to get the cursor vertically centered in the box
- You may or may not want to draw a white box using `Rect()` to overwrite the diagonal lines at the point where you want to place the text.

Then you can then write the text using the `Write()` function with the centering option.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks @JamesG i used your answer as my basis for my fix. I used a different approach though. TCPDF doesn't really have a straightforward class for this specific problem.

Comment: Cool! If you found my answer useful, would you mind accepting it? :-) Thanks.